# Module RPCSEC_GSS skipped unmet check (ConditionPathExists=/etc/krb5.keytab)

Tags: debian, remote, active-directory, kerberos

I use Debian
Kerberos is my worst nightmare.
I can no longer even use windows to Active Directory hijacking.
I have been using Debian on this computer for almost a year.
I am not setting up a network path supporting anything possibly remote.

I have never seen this in my startup journal.
Why am I seeing this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.